# How pass variable submitted in form into 'new' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to send a message to another user. But when I leave a field blank, the controller renders another 'new' action.

Here is the view code that links to the first submit:

```
    <%= link_to 'Send Mail', {:controller => 'messages', :action => 'new', :recipient_id => @profile.id}, :class => 'btn btn-large btn-primary' %>
```

Here is the message#new code:

```
  def new
  @message = Message.new

  @recipient = Profile.find(params[:recipient_id])

end
```

Here is the message#new view code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message do |f| %>

<%= f.input :title %>
<%= f.input :body %>
<%= f.input :recipient_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => @recipient.id} %>
<%= f.input :sender_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => @recipient.id} %>

<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the message#create code:

```
def create
@message = Message.new(params[:message])

if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = "New message created"
  redirect_to @message
else
  flash[:error] = "Did not work"
  @recipient = params[:recipient_id]
  render action: "new"
end
  end
```

How do I get the :recipient_id value submitted in the form and pass into the render new action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rendering `new` method rails won't execute it codes instead it only renders the view(new.html.erb) of the `new` action and you already generating
 a `recipient_id` which is enough for your form to pass the parameter

Try this

```
    def create
        @message = Message.new(params[:message])
        if @message.save
        flash[:notice] = "New message created"
            redirect_to @message
        else
            flash[:error] = "Did not work"
            @recipient = Profile.find(params[:message][:recipient_id])
            render action: "new"
        end
end
```

When rendering the `new` action we have to create the instances manually which is used in the view.

**Note**: If you want generate a new parameter use `redirect_to` method, where `render` uses the previous parameters until a new request is generated

Comment: That worked, thanks! I guess I need a different params value since this is coming from a post request versus the original query string. Also need @recipient to be same class as before.